# Where to locate persistence.xml file in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa

I have my little project for persistence in Tomcat (with Hibernate and Postgres). It's not an EJB project.

I inserted the file "persistence.xml" in the "src" folder of the project: goes well there? I have to copy it in some folder of Tomcat? Should I put the Hibernate libraries inside the "lib" folder of Tomcat?

I have read on the site of Postgres that for Tomcat 4 and 5 should be modified the "server.xml" file, inserting a listing that they give, but they don't specify whether the procedure also applies to Tomcat 6. What do you think about?

Comment: If it's not an EJB project what is it? a web application (.war file)?

Comment: you mean apart from putting it in META-INF from the root of the CLASSPATH? that's really all there is to know

Comment: To Giovanni, I answer: yes.@Giovanni

Comment: To Billy: yes, I mean, in addition to putting it into META-INF, there's something else I've got to do?@Billy Frost